# PHP array with n level deep

Tags: php, logic

Assuming I have an array and recursively want to do some task. I have spent one day for this unable to solve this. May be my logic is not good.
Any help on how to do such thing in an efficient way would save my days.

I have an array with n level deep, looking like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => user1
            [email] => user1@demo.com            
            [depth] => 1            
        ) 
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => user2
            [email] => user2@demo.com            
            [depth] => 1 
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => user2.1
                            [email] => user2.1@demo.com                            
                            [depth] => 2
                        )
                )
        ) 
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => user3
            [email] => user3@demo.com             
            [depth] => 1
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => user3.1
                            [email] => user3.1@demo.com                              
                            [depth] => 2
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => user3.1.1
                                            [email] => user3.1.1@demo.com                                            
                                            [depth] => 3
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => user3.2
                            [email] => user3.2@demo.com                              
                            [depth] => 2                            
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I want to change above array in exactly this format:

```
array(
        0 => array(
            'name' => 'user1',
        ),      
        1 => array(
            'name' => 'user2',      
            'children' => array(
                0 => array(
                    'name' => 'user2.1',                    
                ) ,             
            ) ,
        ) ,     
        2 => array(
            'name' => 'user3',
            'children' => array(
                0 => array(
                    'name' => 'user3.1',
                    'children' => array(
                        0 => array(
                            'name' => 'user3.1.1',                  
                        ) ,             
                    ) ,
                ) ,
                1 => array(
                    'name' => '3.2',
                )               
            ) ,
        ) ,
)
```

**Edited:**
I am using this code and working fine if i want to show data in tree format but unable to push data into array as i want.

```
function displayArrayRecursively($arr, $indent='') {    
    if ($arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {                         
                displayArrayRecursively($value, $indent . '-->');

            } else {                        
                if ($key == 'name')
                {   
                    echo "$indent $value <br>"; 
                }
                else {
                    continue;
                }                       
            }
        }

    }
}       

displayArrayRecursively($userListArray);
```

Can anyone suggest me how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: You should consider take a look at `json` format

Comment: I want a function that return new format and function can be in any language like php or javascript.

Comment: it is difficult to understand what you're trying to do. Can you explain why you want you output array to be like that?

Comment: _"I want a function that return new format"_ - Then write one. You say that you've spent one day trying, then show us what you've tried and what the result is. We don't mind helping you fix your code, but we won't write it all for you. Suggestion, use a recursive function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will do what you want:

```
function process_nodes($nodes) {
    $new = array();
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        $new[] = array('name' => $node['name']);
        if (isset($node[0])) {
            $new[count($new)-1]['children'] = process_nodes($node[0]);
        }
    }
    return $new;
}

print_r(process_nodes($data));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => user1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => user2
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => user2.1
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => user3
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => user3.1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => user3.1.1
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => user3.2
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you Nick! Exact same what I need. Thank you

Comment: Cool. Glad to be of help. You were basically there with your display code, but getting the array pushing right is definitely tricky!

Comment: You are right Nick. I think, I need to improve my logic especially for recursive